# Python - Read txt files from Network shared drive

Tags: python, windows, unc

I am trying to read in data from text files that are moved into a network share drive over a VPN. The overall intent is to be able to loop through the files with yesterday's date (either in the file name, or by the Modified Date) and extract the pipe delimited data separated by "|" and concat it into a pandas df. The issue I am having is actually being able to read files from the network drive. So far I have only been able to figure out how to use os.listdir to identify the file names, but not actually read them. Anyone have any ideas?

This is what I've tried so far that has actually started to pan out = with os.listdir correctly being able to see the Network folder and the files inside - but how would I call the actual files inside (filtered by date or not) to actually get it to work in the loop?

```
import pandas as pd
#folder = os.listdir(r'\\fileshare.com\PATH\TO\FTP\FILES')
folder = (r'\\fileshare.com\PATH\TO\FTP\FILES')

main_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(folder[0]))

for i in range (1, len(folder)):
    data = pd.read_csv(folder[i])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_dataframe, df], axis=1)
print(main_dataframe)
```

I'm pretty new at Python and doing things like this, so I apologize if I refer to anything wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you map that directory to a local drive? Should make things a lot easier.

Comment: If you can list the files, your connection is fine. Do you receive an error? When you list the files, does it return the full file path? If not, you need the full path to open and read the files.

Comment: Possibly, my only thought was that if I kept a connection to the network drive then anyone else in my company that had to adopt the process later on wouldn't have to change much to get it to work on their machines.